# Count the number of clicks for two different buttons with one calculate function

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm sure this is simple but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it

I have two buttons in my C# wpf form: one to mark an answer right, one to mark it wrong.  All I need to do is keep track of how many times each button is clicked, but with ONE calculate method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to show or explain what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "calculate method"? Why not just keep track of the right/wrong button click counts in class-level variables that increment on each respective click?

Comment: I'm sorry, I told you I knew it was super easy.  I don't have anything written for these items because my mind went blank.  I have two buttons, "Right" and "Wrong."  I am supposed to use a method called Calc() that lives in another class.  I am supposed to call the calc() method in each button click event, and the calc() method calculates the total clicks of each button click for each button.  Does that help?  I can't explain it any better.  I know it's as simple as incrementing the variable, but I can't figure out the if statement for the calc() method in a different class.  I am a beginner

Comment: Do you have a pre-defined signature for the `Calculate` method? Can you just pass `true` or `false` to it to indicate right or wrong answer? Each button can call the function, but passes a different value, so the function itself does the correct calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
private int correctCounter = 0; // Declared at class level
private int incorrectCounter = 0; // Declared at class level

private void buttonsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (sender as Button).Text; // Or ((Button)sender).Text;
    if(s == "Correct") { // Change "Correct" to whatever the text of the button is
        correctCounter += 1;
    } else if (s == "Incorrect") {
        incorrectCounter += 1;
    }
    // Do other things
}
```

`string s = (sender as Button).Text;` Will get the text of the button that was clicked and then you just have to compare whatever text is in your two buttons.

**More in depth:**

`(sender as Button)` essentially casts the value of the `sender` to be a `Button`. So you will end up getting properties of the `Button` that called the method. You can also write it as `((Button)sender).Text`

In your case, we can use the `.Text` value of the `Button` object to capture the text of the button. We can then compare the text of the buttons to see which one was clicked.

Comment: The answer is correct but both buttons would have to point to the same event handler unless a Delegate is created..

Comment: I get that, but nothing about the post indicates that the OP doesn't know what a variable is, and you ragged on her twice about it.  I think where she is stuck is wiring two buttons to the same event and then figuring out which one was clicked in the handler - hopefully she WILL understand (sender as Button).Text because that's the answer to her question.

Comment: I'm assuming I'm the OP.  I know what a variable is.  I don't want my button click event to do the calculation.  My two button click events are in my mainWindow.xaml.cs, and the one calculate function that needs to add them separately is in a different class.I need to call the calculate function from both button click events, but have the calculate method tally their clicks separately and assign the totals to the the corresponding variables.  I'll try this answer and work with it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sharon I Hope this helps, next time try to include what you tried with your question. If this answer is the right one, consider voting it correct.

Comment: Sharon, if your calculate function is in a viewmodel, you can look up "wpf command bindings" to learn how to wire the buttons in your view to a function in a viewmodel.  That approach is considered to be better architecture, but is trickier to work with than this answer.  I would start with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Having not worked with WPF itself, I'm not certain that this would work but if you had a public function and a pair of global integer variables, each button could call the public function with a boolean passed as a parameter and have the function increment the two variables.